# Design pattern - duplicate objects in Realm to generate static data

Tags: swift, database-design, realm

I’m a fresh starter with Realm Swift. I did some sort of Realm graph object (seems to work for most people) and a UI mockup to explain you what is the problem with my current design.

---

**An example of the UI workflow**

[image: Menu workflow]

1. The user accesses a list of workouts he created and selects one.
2. The user starts a training session based on the selected workout.
3. The user finishes the workout and then gets the summary page.
4. Later, the user can access a list of past training sessions.
5. The user can select a specific session to see how it went.

**Realm graph object representation**

[image: Realm graph object]

**My current issue**

My problem with the current graph model is related to the 'TrainingSession object' where I need static data to generate charts and statistics.

The WorkoutSession object has *relationships with objects which contain dynamic content*, since I can do the following:

- The user can delete at anytime a workout or change its name, etc
- The user can add or delete an exercise within a workout

By changing a workout or its nested objects (exercises, sets, etc), it will change the information displayed in a training session (screen ⑤). E.g.:

1. Remove pushups in screen ② for Workout A.
2. Check a specific session with Workout A in screen ⑤, then pushups will be removed.

**Approaches**

I really don’t know how to deal with it? As you may guess, I’m trying to reduce data duplicates, so I came with solutions such as:

1. Duplicating all related objects to the workoutSession (Workout, Exercises and so on), but if I do that each time I create a session, it’s going to be huge.
2. Creating some sort of workout/exercise versioning system, so the training session always refer to a specific version of the workout/exercise. A workout is actually working like a blueprint.

---

I hope my visual explanations are helpful enough. If you feel you need me to add some realm code, I’ll do it (but I can’t share the project I’m working on).

Thanks in advance for your precious help ;)

Comment: Did you said you are going to use NoSql? Then why don't save workout data into session object instead of create a relation? Nosql is something I still have to dive in but, relation are expensive, isn't it? How much data can have a workout. I will think another solution, like the workout versioning you said...

Comment: Hello, sorry I didn't get notified about your comment. 
I have no plan using JSON or any other NoSQL techs. Anyway, I did the versioning system and I plan to post the answer soon. I'm currently implementing and testing it. 
It's a bit a pain to manage dependencies between objects but it works (delete if not used, etc.) :)

Comment: I thougth Realm was NoSql, that was the way I used it last time.

Comment: Well, it's very close since it's a dictionary but I wish it would have been the exact same process when talking about dependencies, inverse relationships, etc. Anyway, I should post the solution by the end of today. You'll have a look then.

Comment: You can design a data model, but at some point you have to be aware of the technologies you are gonna use, their advantages and their drawbacks. Anyway is a good oportunity to model a versioning system!

Comment: You’re right. It’s my first time designing a versioning system, I find it quite interesting and challenging at the same time. I’m also syncing realm with Firebase, so I had to use Json and flatten my data. So as you can see, it’s a whole mix :)